# wget not downloading files with 304 Not Modified

Tags: wget, http

I'm trying to download a website recursively using `wget`:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --no-parent --convert-links -e robots=off --domains orteil.dashnet.org orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker
```

It only downloads certain files, while leaving others. Upon closer inspection I figured out it will not download files that return `304 Not Modified`.

This file returns `304 Not Modified` in Inspector and is not downloaded.
[image: A file returning 304]

This file returns `200 OK` in Inspector and is downloaded.
[image: A file returning 200]

I'm guessing this is because `wget` assumes it doesn't need to download files with `304`. How can I force it to download the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

304 Not Modified is sent by the server in response to a `If-Modified-Since` header.  It is supposed to tell the client that the copy he has is up to date.  This header in turn is sent by `wget` because the file already exists in the output directory with some timestamp.

So the obvious way to force a download is to start with an empty output directory.

You might be having issues because you are using `--convert-links` and not `--backup-converted`, since `--convert-links` changes the timestamp on the file (thus making it appear more recent).

Edit: in more recent `wget`s than I was testing with, one can also add `--no-if-modified-since`